# I need to make sure 2 DB are the same

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm doing it programmatically (I'm a newbie to sql) I'm getting the data per table within first DB using with being a value from a list of table names that I need to make sure are

1. there
2. if there have the corresponding values in the same table in
   DB X list all the fields that do not have the same values and the
   value in below
3. Table that does match listing the table, field name, row,

   ```
   "SELECT * FROM [Dev.Chris21].[dbo].[" & PayrollTablemaskedarray(xxxxxx-2) & "]"
   ```

I can copy the whole thing into excel but I'm wondering is there a way to do this using sql?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27196083/edit) your question to improve your grammar, tell us what database you are using (MS SQL Server Enterprise?), what `PayrollTablemaskedarray` is, and provide examples of the kind of result you are trying to get, as I cannot understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention that you're doing it programmically I assume you're using visual studio. If so you can take advantage of SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) to do comparisons of two database schemas or two database data sets.  You get this out of the box with VS2012 or VS2013 (and earlier versions too). Might be worth a look...

Comment: I'm using an automated tool called qtp

Comment: I'm not using visual studio - I'm using an automation tool called UFT or vbsedit